# Initialize value from parent constructor?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have some parameter in the constructor. I need to convert it to something else and give it to the parent constructor. But the problem is that I want to remember the result of the conversion (which I give to the parent constructor) and I don't need to store it in the base class.
How initialize value in the parent constructor argument? Like "val" in base constructor?

```
    protected open class BindingViewHolder(binding: ViewDataBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    protected open class ModelViewHolder<Model : Identifiable<*>?, Binding : ViewDataBinding>(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        inflateBinding: (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Boolean) -> Binding
    ) : BindingViewHolder(parent.inflateChildBinding(inflateBinding)) {
        //some code
    }
```

I have one problem in this code. I cant "val" "parent.inflateChildBinding(inflateBinding)"

Comment: hmm... couldn't you do something like `) : BindingViewHolder(memoize(parent.inflateChildBinding(inflateBinding)))` and have the `fun memoize(whatever: Any) { val memo = whatever, return whatever }` sort of method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you might as well make the `binding` a property in the first class. You also need to use the exact type of binding depending on the case, so you should apply generics like this:

```
protected open class BindingViewHolder<T: ViewDataBinding>(val binding: T) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

At this point, your second class can be merged into the first class ad a secondary constructor so we can avoid overuse of inheritance:

```
protected open class BindingViewHolder<T: ViewDataBinding>(val binding: T) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    constructor(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        inflateBinding: (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Boolean) -> T
    ): this(parent.inflateChildBinding(inflateBinding))
}
```

If desired, you can make the primary constructor private. The property in it will still be public.

---

To answer your literal question, you would make a primary constructor with the parameter you want to keep as a property and then make a secondary constructor with the parameters you need. It would basically look like my example above but with your second class, and the primary constructor  only passing the `binding` to the superconsttuctor.

Comment: can you help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74549206/11560810). I know you can be proper guidance. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result that you want to remember in a `SharedPreference` and retrieve it in the other class.

Storing data in SharedPreference

```
val sharedPref = context?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
with (sharedPref.edit()) {
    putInt(getString(R.string.converted_value), convertedValue)
    apply()
}
```

Retrieving data from `SharedPreference`

```
val sharedPref = context?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

I don't fully understand your question. If your goal is to get the value from the previous class, just pass them to the new class's constructor.

Read more on `SharedPreference` [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

Comment: I mean store as value. How initilize value in the parent constructor argument? Like "val" in base constructor?

Comment: `val convertedVal : String = "value from constructor"` assuming the value type is a string. Otherwise, replace `String` with your preferred type.

Comment: "I have some parameter in the constructor. I need to CONVERT it to something else". If i have string (as param in base construstor) i give parent constructor doSomethingFunction(paramString) and val it